# Qt - How to Build one Dynamic Library in a project which depends on other dynamic library

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I have Two Dynamic Library
library1.so
library2.so   (Using library1.so , path is absolute)

in which library2.so is using library1.so, so when i am building my project which is using library2.so(absolute path) its giving error for all the methods(undefined reference) in library1.so

Answer (score 1):

In your qmake config you can add arbitrary libs:

```
LIBS += -llibrary2
```

OR

```
LIBS += /abspath/to/library2.so
```

Comment: in the first case you probably should provide `-L $librarydir` to indicate where is library2, unless it is already in the default qmake library path.

Comment: I have done this but my project debug is giving error for all the members of library1.so